# RAD tools for .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, rad

I'm new at web development and have been looking at some RAD tools for Asp.Net. It is hard to compare what's on the market. The tool must be simple to use and should be easy to modify and add custom business logic to it.

Would like to hear the opinion of some of you guys before considering to use any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

Comment: Sorry for asking again but Can you tell me why i should go for Webmatrix? I have also heard lot about Iron Speed.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a big question.
There are a lot on the market. If you accept the learning curve then I suppose that they are "Ok" for Quick & Dirty Application.
I also believe that RAD tools or (Automatic Application Development Tools) are good when you have a lot small projects to accomplish in a very limited time, and you work in a "one_man_show"-mode ;)

A good discussion on this subject you can find [here](http://justgeeks.blogspot.gr/2013/11/aspnet-code-generators-reviewed-for.html). Personally I also use [ASP.Net Maker](http://www.hkvstore.com/aspnetmaker/), a very fair solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use OutSystems - RAD platform that generates standard.Net. It was hard to learn because it requires an entirely diffrent mindset, but it worth. There is a free version to try it out (check [here](https://www.outsystems.com/get-started/)). No need to setup a server or database - just download the IDE and use a personal environment in the cloud.

Tip: completing the first tutorial (how to build an app in 5 minutes) will give you an overview of how it works.

cheers,
V